# Check if an entered number is numeric

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to run the following code but it is not working:

```
        if( is_numeric( $primary_mobile_number ) ) {
            echo json_encode( array( 'success' => false, 'msg' => esc_html__('The phone number is 
            incorect.', 'login-register') ) );
            wp_die();
        }
```

Comment: You are not explaining more details such as environment, what you are trying to accomplish, what is the current and the expected output. I suggest you to edit both topic and text.

Comment: So if something is numeric, it isn't a phone number or is it just a typo that you are missing `!` in `!is_numeric()`?

Comment: Thank you so much, yes I was missing the "!"

Answer (score -1):

I was missing the ! before is_numeric

```
if( !is_numeric( $primary_mobile_number ) ) {
            echo json_encode( array( 'success' => false, 'msg' => esc_html__('The phone number is 
            incorect.', 'login-register') ) );
            wp_die();
        }
```

Thank you Vivek_23